# php - can't execute mysql that works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have this table for a game

```
scores (user,score)
```

with some entries in it, i have this query:

```
SET @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC
```

it works in phpmyadmin but it doesn't work with php code

```
$query = "set @row_num = 0; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**php is properly connected to mysql database**, i do other queries before that and everything works

it says:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY s' at line 1
```

What do you think it could be?
Thank you,
Alessandro

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split in 2 queries:

```
$query = "set @row_num = 0;";
$query2 = " SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$result1 = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: Ok i didn't know this, thank you, and now how can i make a SELECT to the resulted table?

Comment: Have you try to do an inner select?

Comment: I don't know how to do inner selects, can you give me an example?

Comment: `code` SET @row_num = 0; 
`code` SELECT * FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC) WHERE row_num=3;

How can i make this work?

Comment: SELECT name FROM world
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name='Russia');
So use your previous select inside condition of another one. Or inside FROM: SELECT name FROM (SELECT * FROM world WHERE name='Russia');

Answer (score 6):

This is because phpMyAdmin splits queries on semi-colons for you. The MySQL server does **not** do this, and neither does the PHP `mysql` extension.

You'll need to separate these out into two separate calls to `mysql_query`

Side note: The PHP `mysql` extension is deprecated and it's recommended that you use `PDO` or `mysqli` for any new code. Please keep that in mind during your future development.

Comment: Ok i didn't know this, thank you, and now how can i make a SELECT to the resulted table?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `mysql_query` is depricated.

You cannot run two queries in a single call of `mysql_query`

```
$query = "set @row_num = 0; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC";
```

You have to do like below:

```
$query1= "set @row_num = 0;";
$query2 = "SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: Ok i didn't know this, thank you, and now how can i make a SELECT to the resulted table?